# How to get file name with a inherit class?

Tags: ruby, inheritance

I want to get the file name of a ruby class with a inherit function. Something like that :

```
# a.rb
class A
  def get_file()
    __FILE__
  end
end

# b.rb
class B < A
end

# c.rb
myobj = B.new()
puts myobj.get_file()
```

b.rb is expected, but I have a.rb.

I have a lot of class like B, so I don't want to add a function to each class inherited of A. I would like to add a generic method in the A class to get the good file.
Somebody can help me please ?

Eric

Comment: It makes sense because the `get_file` method is actually in the `a.rb` file.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks to Arup and Jesse to help me. I have found the solution with their esponse.

Here is my solution :

**a.rb**

```
class A
  # Called from b.rb at `class A < B`. `subclass` is the Class object B.
  # This method makes sure every subclass (class B, class C...)
  # has #get_file defined correctly for instances of the subclass.
  def self.inherited (subclass)
    subclass.instance_eval do
      # This array contains strings like "/path/to/a.rb:3:in `instance_eval'".
      strings_ary = caller

      # We look for the first string containing "(root)".
      require_index = strings_ary.index {|x| x.include?("(root)") }
      require_string = strings_ary[require_index]
      # We use a regex to extract the filepath from require_string.
      filepath = require_string[/^(.*):\d+:in `\(root\)'/, 1]
      # This defines the method #get_file for instances of `subclass`.
      define_method(:get_file) { filepath }
    end
  end

  # For instances of class A only, we use the __FILE__ keyword.
  # This method is overwritten by the #get_file method defined above.
  def get_file
    __FILE__
  end
end
```

**b.rb**

```
class B < A
end
```

**c.rb**

```
require_relative 'a'
require_relative 'b'

p A.new.get_file
p B.new.get_file
```

**the output of c.rb**

```
"<path>/Test/lib/tmp/a.rb"
"<path>/Test/lib/tmp/b.rb"
```

@Jesse => I don't know why your solution didn't work on my desk. The keyword *top (required)* didn't exists, I have replace it by *(root)* with a index search and not rindex. I'm on ruby 1.7.3. The output of my caller is that :

```
<path>/Test/lib/tmp/a.rb:6:in `instance_eval'
<path>/Test/lib/tmp/a.rb:6:in `inherited'
<path>/Test/lib/tmp/b.rb:4:in `(root)'
<path>/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1:in `require'
<path>/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:1:in `(root)'
<path>/jruby-1.7.3/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
<path>\Test\lib\tmp\c.rb:5:in `(root)'
```

Thanks again for your help.

Eric

Comment: -1. This is not doing what you said you wanted. This code defines `get_file` on `B`. You said you do not want to.

Comment: @sawa, maybe my problem was not explained correctly. The problem was how to define a get_file method without change all the inherits class (a lot of class were concerned). The solution to create a get_file in the father class did'nt work, the solution of jesse is works really good.

Comment: I have edited the original post, I hope it's more undersandable ... :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have my directory :

```
-home
  |-kirti
     |-workpspace
         |-Ruby
            |- a.rb
            |- b.rb
            |- c.rb
```

Below are the file contents :

**a.rb**

```
class A
  def get_file()
    [__FILE__,$0]
  end
end
```

**b.rb**

```
require_relative 'a.rb'

class B < A
end
```

**c.rb**

```
require_relative 'b.rb'

myobj = B.new()
puts myobj.get_file()
```

Now I am running the code :

```
(arup~>Ruby)$ ruby c.rb
/home/kirti/workspace/Ruby/a.rb
c.rb
(arup~>Ruby)$
```

Now let me first put the the documentation of [`__FILE__`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-__FILE__)

> The name of the file currently being executed, including path relative to the directory where the application was started up (or the current directory, if it has been changed). *The **current file** is, in some cases, different from the **startup file** for the running application, which is available in the global variable `$0`.*

From the doc, it is clear `__FILE__` is a current file location, which is different from the start-up file `$0`. So **c.rb** is your start-up file, but the current file is **/home/kirti/workspace/Ruby/a.rb**.

Basically, the value of the magic variable `__FILE__` is a relative path that is created and stored (**but never updated**) when your file is loaded. Now in your case you kept it inside the file `a.rb`, so it holds the */home/kirti/workspace/Ruby/a.rb*.

`class B < A ;end`, it means you are adding the `A`, to the ancestor chain of class `B`. It doesn't mean the methods from `A` will be added to `B`. `get_file` method is still in the cass `A`. Your object `myobj`, will search the method `get_file` first inside the class `B`, if not found then into the class(s) and module(s), that are in the ancestor chain. Now as `get_file` inside the class `A`, and the `A` is in the file `a.rb`, so the value of `__FILE__` should be set to *`/home/kirti/workspace/Ruby/a.rb`*, when **a.rb** was loaded first time. Now `require_relative 'a.rb'` made available the class `A`, to the file **b.rb**, but the value of `__FILE__` will not be updated.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Arup, I have already understood this concept and why there is a problem. But I really need to get the file without defined a new getFile in B.rb. Now, I will read Jesse's reponse. It seems it is possible :)